# How to write a java program that receives a character and keep asking insert it until it is a certain character

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm trying to make a program that receives a character from
keyboard until the character is s or n, and then print it on screen.

I wrote this code, but I can't understand why the program keeps asking me to insert a character, even if it's s or n.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prep4{

    public static void main(String[] args){
    char c;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("Type in a character");
            c = kb.next().charAt(0);
        } while(c != 's' || c != 'S' || c != 'n' || c != 'N');
    System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to end the do-while loop to print s or n, if typed in.
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be with && because it will always not equal one of those.

```
while(c != 's' && c != 'S' && c != 'n' && c != 'N')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
do{
         System.out.println("Type in a character");
         c = kb.next().charAt(0);
      } while(c != 's' && c != 'S' && c != 'n' && c != 'N');
```

You should refer to [De morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

(not a) OR (not b)  ⟷  not (a AND b)

Applying this rule to your condition, it'll be equivalent to:

```
while((c != 's') && (c != 'S') && (c != 'n') && (c != 'N'))
```